# Объединение нескольких записей с одинаковым названием в одно

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wordpress-плагины

На сайте WP есть множество записей, каждая запись имеет одинаковые метатеги как артикул, вес допустим. Есть одинаковые записи которые отличаются друг от друга допустим только по этим мета тегам. А описание и название записи одно и тоже. Как реализовать функцию вывода записей без множественных копий. А почему реализовывал именно используя дубликаты записей, для того что бы потом можно было выгружать в таблицу Excel, отдельными позициями для дальнейшей работы.

Что имею и что хочу.

2 записи с одинаковыми названиями и описанием.
У одной метаполе артикул 151321, вес 14 кг; а у второй 4513424, вес 1 кг;

Как мне вывести два поста как одну, но при этом сохранить отдельные позиции для выгрузки в excel?

Comment: *вывести два поста как одну, но при этом сохранить отдельные позиции* Вы уж определитесь - объединять две записи в одну или оставлять две... А вообще - сделайте два запроса. Один объединяет и отображается на экране, второй не объединяет и экспортируется в Excel.

Comment: Ну вот у меня и вопрос, как выводить записи без повторений в списке записей, но со всеми данными.

Comment: *как выводить записи без повторений но со всеми данными* Никак - это противоречивое требование. Если "без повторений" - значит, какие-то данные будут отброшены, но в этом случае не может быть "со всеми данными". PS. Попробуйте показать пример того, что Вы хотите - исходные данные (5-6 записей) и требуемый результат на этих данных.

Comment: Допустим есть два записи с названиями одинаковыми. Показывает в списке один пост только. заходя в него видим описание первого поста допустим. а мета теги обоих.

Comment: Если есть товары - это уже ИМ. А у товаров есть *вариации*. Это то, что тебе нужно.